# Как получать новые сообщения из канала?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Пишу программу на [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как получать новые сообщёния из канала, копировать и публиковать в другой?

Answer (score 0):

1) Читаем

```
tlg_client = TelegramClient(tlg_sess_name, tlg_api_id, tlg_api_hash, proxy=proxy)

messages = tlg_client.get_messages('entity канала', limit=dialog.unread_count)
```

2) Отправляем

```
tlg_client.send_message(tlg_outchannel, text)
```